# How to resolve the no viable input error in racket?

Tags: parsing, racket, antlr

I've been trying to execute the following program in a parser

```
#lang racket
( define ( highest-number xs )
  ( define ( max x1 x2 )
    ( if ( > x1 x2) x1 x2 ) )
  ( foldl max ( first xs ) ( rest xs ) )
```

The error that is generated is as follows :
*line 3:4 no viable alternative at input '( define'*

These are my rules :

```
grammar hello;

program
    : defOrExpr+ EOF
    ;

defOrExpr
    : definition
    | expr
    | testCase
    | libraryRequire
    ;

definition
    : '(' 'define' '(' name NAME+ ')' expr ')'
    | '(' 'define' name expr ')'
    | '(' 'define-struct' name '(' name* ')' ')'
    ;
```

Comment: Please add a complete grammar that produces the error you mention. The partial grammar you posted is not enough to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As Bart mentioned, it's much easier to help if there's a buildable grammar and sample input to reproduce your problem.)

In this case, I think the problem is fairly obvious.

Your `definition` rule does not contain an alternative that allows for a nested `definition`, and your sample input has a nested definition.

I'm not familiar enough with Racket to suggest an alternative to address the issue, but that's why you're getting your error.  (it's on the  `( define ( max x1 x2 )` part, not the first `define`)